# Understanding Tcl_DeleteInterp() API

Tags: tcl

I have some problem with Tcl_DeleteInterp() API (on solaris). I have used this Tcl_DeleteInterp() in my application to delete interpreter. The strange thing i found is the process which uses this API hangs about 20 minutes. I attached the process with truss command and found that the process continueously executing the below functions for almost 20 min.

```
15.6541  0.0002 -> libtcl8.4:Tcl_DeleteInterp(0x41748, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
15.6580  0.0039   -> libc:free(0x288f8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
15.6583  0.0003   -> libc:mutex_unlock(0xff0424e8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
15.6584  0.0001   <- libc:free() = 0
15.6588  0.0004   -> libc:free(0x474b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)*
...
...
```

Can someone help me on this why the function Tcl_DeleteInterp calling these functions?
I have also checked the implementation done for Tcl_DeleteInterp() , but didn't find any clue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Tcl_DeleteInterp` deletes a Tcl interpreter context. As part of that, it destroys the namespaces, commands and variables in that interpreter (Tcl doesn't have *true* globals; everything is always local to a specific interpreter context). That deletion in turn happens to release memory back to the main memory manager and possibly the OS; that's why `free()` is called; it might be called indirectly in some configurations, but it will be called. (If there's an active execution in the interpreter context — that is, a call to `Tcl_Eval()` or one of its related functions — some of the deletions will be postponed until the execution finishes.) There are also some callbacks (well, quite a lot of them) that can be set to detect various deletions; those can (and quite probably will) free things as well.

I've no idea what's causing the hangs, but at a guess it looks like you've got another thread that's hammering the system memory allocator, keeping the global lock for the memory allocator rather too tightly held. If that's the case, that's pretty nasty. You might in that case be best off trying to upgrade to a thread-enabled build of Tcl 8.5 or 8.6 (I'd recommend that anyway; 8.4 is out of non-commercial support now) as that uses a custom memory allocator that doesn't allocate (and deallocate) nearly so often from the global memory pool. I *don't* know that that will fix things; I suspect the bug is not in Tcl's implementation but in other code. (It surely isn't in a Tcl script unless you've got some fancy extension code which is causing the problems.)